# In my plugin, why does $_SESSION only work when I am logged in in wp-admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, plugins

I have developed a wordpress plugin for client portal. I use php session for login. It work for maximum site, but some of website `$_SESSION` is "only work if i login to wp-admin", otherwise `$_SESSION` does not work.

If i login to wp-admin then i get data in `$_SESSION` but if i logout from wp-admin then `$_SESSION` is empty

**For start session i use this**

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'register_my_session'));
function register_my_session()
{
    if( !session_id() ) session_start();    
}
```

Please can tell me what's wrong with me ?

Thank's advance .

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194618/why-does-session-only-work-when-i-am-logged-in

Comment: @SahilManchanda that issue for session_start();  and i have already tried .

Comment: please try using this `ob_get_clean(); ob_start(); session_start();`

Comment: @DhavalPurohit thank's . But it does not work !!

Comment: @MahidulIslam ok

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

add_action('admin_init', 'register_my_session');